# Method created during runtime changes the parameter order of another method call depending on how it is run

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I implement interfaces during runtime using `Reflection.Emit` and create their defined methods.

Example definition of a method in the interface:

```cs
IFoo DoSomething(IBar bar, string name);
```

To create the methods I do the following:

```cs
var args = methodInfo.GetParameters();

MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(methodInfo.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
    methodInfo.ReturnType, (from arg in args select arg.ParameterType).ToArray());
typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, methodInfo);

var generator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodInfo.ReturnType);

if (args.Any())
{
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, args.Length);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));

    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, i);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, i + 1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
    }
}
else
{
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
}

generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(ISomeType).GetMethod(nameof(ISomeType.Test), new[] {typeof(Type), typeof(object[])}), null);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

This generates me for example my `DoSomething(IBar bar, string name)` method of the interface.
All generated methods call the method `Test()` of `ISomeType`.

This is the method `Test()`:

```cs
public object Test(Type type, object[] arguments)
{
   //do something
}
```

When I run my application and call the `DoSomething()` method, the parameters are passed the wrong way (`object[]` first and `Type` second) to `Test()`, which obviously leads to an exception.

But when I run a unit test and call the `DoSomething()` method, the parameters are passed correctly (`Type` first and `object[]` second) to `Test()`.

Why is there a difference in which order the parameters are passed to the `Test()` method depending on how it is run?

Comment: the "no args" case looks **very** wrong - why are you loading an int32 zero? should that be `Ldnull`? Or did you intend to create an empty array immediately after loading zero? (in which case, you might prefer to invoke `Array.Empty<T>()` for the correct `T`

Comment: also, the use of `Ldc_I4_S` looks wrong; a: it will fail horribly if it is more than 254, and b: I *think* you need to explicitly cast that to `byte`, i.e. `(byte)i` and `(byte)(i+1)`; it also looks very unreliable if the original arguments are reference-types - you'll need a `Box`

Comment: "But when I run a unit test" - any chance the unit test and application are running in different modes re x86/x64? this could tie into the `Ldc_I4_0` usage, which would be illegal but *kinda OK* on x86, but which would be illegal and *very bad* on x64

Comment: You might also need the `byte` cast with `generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, (byte)args.Length);`

Comment: @MarcGravell: The idea behind the `Ldc_I4_0` in the no args case was to pass an empty array to the function. I will try change that the way you suggested.
Yeah it's true that it would fail for more than 254, that's not a real use case right now though I think. 
Wouldn't there be an exception if the `byte` cast was needed?

Comment: I run both the application and the unit test from Visual Studio, with the `Any CPU` setting

Comment: "Wouldn't there be an exception if the byte cast was needed" - no, IIRC it just happily emits invalid IL; "The idea behind the Ldc_I4_0 in the no args case was to pass an empty array to the function." - but you didn't pass an empty array - you passed a zero int32

Comment: "I run both the application and the unit test from Visual Studio, with the Any CPU setting" - so... yes, probably one is x86 and one is x64, then (devenv is a 32-bit program)

Comment: also: pro tip; if IL-emit is fighting you, [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) is a great idea; it has *basically* the same API surface, but it is **great** at giving very clear error messages if you've done something *even remotely* invalid. (project home: https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thank you, I will test it out with your suggestions and also take a look at Sigil.

Comment: @MarcGravell: When using Sigil I encounter the problem that `LoadConstant(Type)` (which is the equivalent to `Ldtoken`) pushes a `RuntimeTypeHandle` instead of the `Type` onto the stack.
This leads to a `SigilVerificationException` that `CallVirtual` expected another parameter type than the type it got.

Comment: In my specific case I can evade the problem by using a generic method `Test<T>(object[] arguments)`, this way there is only one parameter and the order can't get messed up

Comment: that (`RuntimeTypeHandle`) actually sounds correct; `ldtoken` doesn't push a `Type` *either* - the correct usage to get a `Type` is `ldtoken` then `Type.GetTypeFromHandle` - see https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAEMEDZtyYDCmA3qppdljvjACyYCyAFAJRkVXc4CcLwAJ4AHAKYB7AGYsibNgG4ulAL6plQA== - it sounds like sigil is correctly spotting an error :)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Wow this worked like a charm. I needed to get the correct type with `GetTypeFromHandle` as you said and also cast the return value to the return type of the method, and now it is working like expected.  
The parameter order stays the same no matter how it gets executed.  
Thank you very much for your continuous help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a lot of help of [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) in the comments I found out what to do to get this problem fixed.
First of all I had an error in the way I created my methods.

The case when a method has no arguments has to be changed from

```cs
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
```

that pushes just a `0` as `Int32` onto the stack, to

```cs
MethodInfo emptyArray = typeof(Array).GetMethod(nameof(Array.Empty))?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));
generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, emptyArray, null);
```

which really pushes an empty array to the stack that will get passed as an argument to the `Test()` function.

To fix the problem with the wrong parameter order there are two possible solutions in my specific case:

**(1) More changes to the generated IL code:**

1. Really push the return type of the method as a `Type` and not a `RuntimeTypeHandle`:

   ```cs
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodInfo.ReturnType);

   MethodInfo getTypeFromHandle = typeof(Type).GetMethod(nameof(Type.GetTypeFromHandle));
   generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, getTypeFromHandle, null);
   ```
2. Cast the return type of `Test()` to the wanted return type of the method before returning:

   ```cs
   generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(ISomeType).GetMethod(nameof(ISomeType.Test), new[] {typeof(Type), typeof(object[])}), null);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, methodInfo.ReturnType);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
   ```

**(2) Convert `Test()` method to a generic method:**

In case you have parameters as a `Type` you can convert your method to a generic method:

```cs
public T Test<T>(object[] arguments)
{
   //do something
}
```

If you decide to do so, you will have to change some of the IL code generation as well:

1. Don't push return type of the method to the stack:

   Remove this line:

   ```cs
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodInfo.ReturnType);
   ```
2. Change the call of `Test()`:

   ```cs
   MethodInfo test = typeof(ISomeType).GetMethod(nameof(ISomeType.Test), new[] { typeof(object[]) }).MakeGenericMethod(methodInfo.ReturnType);
   generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, test, null);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
   ```

   You also don't have to cast the return value in this case because your method `Test()` already returns the correct type with `T`.

With any of those two solutions the `Test()` method gets call with the correct parameter order regardless of how it is called (application or unit test).

Another [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443465/method-created-during-runtime-changes-the-parameter-order-of-another-method-call?noredirect=1#comment99480964_56443465) of Marc Gravell was to use [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) to get clear error messages when your generated IL code is invalid. And no matter which of the two solutions above you are choosing I can only recommend to do so.